# Very large database insert fails - MySQL, JPA 2, WildFly 8

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink, wildfly

MySQL Community Server v5.6.19
JPA 2
EclipseLink
WildFly 8
Java EE 7
JDK 1.8
Container Managed Persistence

I'm trying to load a very large amount of reference data from an XML file and store it in a MySQL database.

In total there are approximately 60,000 records that need to be written to the DB.

All is well for the first 7,500 records or so, but then I get the following:-

```
    00:06:37,157 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff0a00000b:2d6361a7:5435c20e:22 in state  RUN
    00:06:37,161 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff0a00000b:2d6361a7:5435c20e:22 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
    00:06:37,161 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffff0a00000b:2d6361a7:5435c20e:22 aborting with 1 threads active!

    00:06:37,184 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff0a00000b:2d6361a7:5435c20e:22
    00:06:37,193 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (default task-38) javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
    00:06:37,193 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-38) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component MyItemDAO for method public java.lang.Object model.dao.BaseDAO.update(java.lang.Object): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:163) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.CR2.jar:8.1.0.CR2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:253) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.CR2.jar:8.1.0.CR2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:342) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.CR2.jar:8.1.0.CR2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.CR2.jar:8.1.0.CR2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
```

And then a lot more warnings and errors.  All subsequent insert statements fail.

I've searched based on the ARJUNA error code, but the answers I've found seem to suggest that the database or a table is being locked due to a mysqldump.  This is not the case for me - there is no mysqldump in progress.

Another suggestion that I've seen is that the number of MySQL connections might be being exhausted, but I'm not sure how connections are allocated by the JPA.  I have two tables that are being updated, and I'm merging and then flushing each entity as soon as it is fully populated from the source data file.

My data file and processing looks like this...

```
    <!-- Reference data file -->
    <!-- Contains 1 x elem_1 record, approx 1000 elem_2 records, and approx 60,000 elem_3 records -->
    <!-- There is a varying number of elem_3 records per elem_2 record -->

    <elem_1 attr1="" attr2="">  <!-- Create detached elem_1 entity -->
    <!-- Persist elem_1 entity and flush elem_1 EM  -->

        <elem_2 attr1="">  <!-- Create detached elem_2 entity -->
            <val_1>Value..</val_1>  <!-- Add value to detached entity  -->
            <val_2>Value..</val_2>  <!-- Add value to detached entity  -->
            <val_3>Value..</val_3>  <!-- Add value to detached entity  -->

            <!-- Persist elem_2 entity and flush elem_2 EM  -->

            <elem_3 attr1="" attr2="" attr3="">  <!-- Create detached elem_3 entity -->
                <child_1>Value..</child_1>  <!-- Add value to detached entity  -->
                <child_2>Value..</child_2>  <!-- Add value to detached entity  -->
                <child_3>Value..</child_3>  <!-- Add value to detached entity  -->
            </elem_3>  <!-- Persist elem_3 entity and flush elem_3 EM -->

            <!-- Repeat above elem_3 process for all elem_3 records -->

            <!-- Call clear() on elem_3 EM -->

        </elem_2>  <!-- Flush elem_2 EM then call clear() on elem_2 EM -->

        <!-- Repeat above elem_2 process for all elem_2 records -->

    </elem_1>
```

Can anyone suggest what might be causing this please?  More importantly, how do I resolve it so that I can load all of the data?

Comment: do you see the error log of mysql?

Comment: `Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)`. Are you invoking flush with a transaction opened?

Comment: @Widrogo - MySQL doesn't seem to be creating log files (or at least I can't find them) so I'll have to check the config and get back to you.

Comment: @uaiHebert - I am using Container Managed Persistence and PersistenceContext injection on each entity.  There is no problem for the first 7,500 iterations (all calling the same merge(...) and flush(...) methods on the same DAO) so I don't think this is anything to do with a missing transaction. I realise that's what the error message suggests, but I think that's after the DB connection (and therefore the Entity Manager and any transaction support) has failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by the 'Use JTA' option in the WildFly JDBC Datasource Configuration being set to false.

After changing this setting to true I was able to remove all of the spurious dao.clear() calls and the query ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the transaction manager has a timeout for transactions, and your massive insert exceeds the timeout, so the transaction reaper aborts the long running transaction and the following insert fails.

There's probably a config setting to increase the timeout, but IMHO you'd better split your massive insert into smaller batches with separate transactions.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the layout of the source data, and included comments showing the JTA processing that I'm doing.  My understanding is that due to the way I'm processing each record from the file individually, I have a large number of very small inserts/transactions that happen very quickly, and not one large insert/transaction that takes an age.  Please correct me if I am wrong.